# How do I loop through JSON to parse and display each item?

Tags: c#, json, xamarin

I am trying to pull data and display it from a rest API using C#. However I am having trouble looping through it and displaying each individual item I have tried code like so

```
private void ParseAndDisplay(JsonValue json)
{
    JsonValue teamData = json["teams"];
    TextView name = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtName);

    foreach(var team in teamData)
    {
        name.Text = team["name"];
    }
}
```

What is it I do differently? For now I am simply trying to loop through and display all the teams "name" in one text view.

Comment: Why not just Deserialize it to object ?

Comment: Deserialize the object to achive your results.

Comment: Thanks guys I am quite new to using apis and this sort of stuff do you know any good tutorials about deserializing this type of data?

Comment: can you show the incoming data ?

Comment: You Can use dynamic keyword if your dont want create class [see](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object)

Answer (score 0):

Ok.
lets assume this is your json object:

```
{"Tables":[
  {"field1":1,"field2":2}
  ,{"field1":1,"field2":2
  }]}
```

at first we create a object like this:

```
public class Table
{
    public int field1 { get; set; }
    public int field2 { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Table> Tables { get; set; }
}
```

then just deserilize your json into object then iterate it like this:

```
    var objs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(yourJson);
    foreach(var t in objs.Tables)
    {
        //do something
    }
```